# Integrating Azure ML to non-ACR image repositories

Tags: artifactory, azure-machine-learning-service, azure-container-registry

Is there a methodology/pattern to redirect Azure ML to non-ACR image repositories like jfrog artifactory for all supported Azure ML functionalities?

Potential solution that we are exploring is to build custom images on Artifactory that does not require Azure ML customization, in that scenario AML only pulls and runs pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The only supported way in AzureML to build a derived image is ACR (with 2 exceptions like local build and image build on AzureML Compute).

Already built image can pulled from any registry, so if you manage the image separately you can use them as is in AzureML.